# ANTLR lexer mode match any text - extraneous input

Tags: antlr4

I switch modes so I can accept any text inside a grammar. This example doesn't include the complexity of the real life situation. I adapted an exampled from the ANTLR book.

**Lexer**

```
parser grammar StringsParser;

@header {
    package lexertest;
}
options { tokenVocab=StringsLexer; }

test:quotedString+;
quotedString:LQUOTE content;  
content:TEXT+?;
```

**Parser**

```
lexer grammar StringsLexer;

LQUOTE : '"' -> mode(STR) ;
WS     : [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip ;

mode STR;

STRING : '"' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
TEXT   : .;
```

**Test Input**

```
"hi"
"mom"
```

Gives me:

```
line 1:3 extraneous input '"' expecting {<EOF>, LQUOTE, TEXT}
line 2:4 extraneous input '"' expecting {<EOF>, LQUOTE, TEXT}
```

How do I fix this so I don't get the above error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STR mode is emitting both TEXT and STRING tokens.  The 'quotedString' rule needs to be:

```
quotedString : LQUOTE content STRING ;
```